# Writing into cassandra 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0. changed into 0001-01-01 10:30:00?

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, export-to-csv

I am reading a csv  file from spark as data frame . For column x have time stamp value,  0001-01-01 00:00:00.0.

After writing a data frame to Cassandra table, I found timestamp value is changed,
 0001-01-01 10:30:00
Any one help me..

Comment: did you check the timestamp in spark dataframe before you write to cassandra table?

Comment: Yes,but time stamp is changing..

Comment: is it that when you view in dataframe its `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0` and when you write to cassandra its `0001-01-01 10:30:00` . Is that so?

Comment: but now it's self problem is not resolved.

Comment: what do you mean by `self problem is not resolved`?

Comment: I mean data frame writing to table itself 0001-01-01 00:00:00 is there. But after writing into table changes like 0001-01-01 10:30:00

Comment: your date is not a valid date. Try changing the input date to valid date and time and see if the problem still exists

Comment: that date format is correct and Casandra database acceptable date format is  0001-01-01 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the timezone differs. Also, you might validate that it's not converting from your local timezone into GMT.

Comment: yes, I checked time zone itself but issue is not resolved at.

Comment: @ponnagantichandu have you checked to make sure that it's not storing in GMT?